# Are Windows 2000 SP4 installation CDs home brewed?

Tags: windows, windows-2000

I want to buy the latest official available Windows 2000 (Desktop) CD in both German & English.

On https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-nt-2000/final there are CD images without service pack and some include SP1, SP2, SP3 and SP4.

I wonder if they are official or home brewed?

I tried to find images of SP4 CDs so I can be sure. I found [this](https://ia802207.us.archive.org/21/items/Win2000SRV-Turkish-SP4/ZRMSFPP_TR.png) image. Of course the black text has been added but in the upper right corner it says "1-4 işlemci sürümü". I don't know if this is the service pack version. Google translated it to *processor version* which doesn't make sense.

Please if you answer the question also tell me if the SP version is visible on the CD print.

Comment: Why does "1-4 processor version" not make sense?

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't know what kind of processor version they could mean? I think Win2000 is made for x86. For example if they say it's for i386 processor version that could make sense. But I don't know what "1-4 processor version" could mean.

Comment: The number of CPUs supported varied by edition. Pro 2, Server 4, Advanced Server 8 and Datacenter Server 16-32.

Comment: @Brian Is this a license thing or does it refer to multi-CPU computers? Or do you mean cores? Because I know mainboards having 2 CPUs but never heard about 32. 

Comment: @zomega It was one core per socket with 1-8 sockets on x86. Very late in Windows 2000 life Xeons did have 2 cores per socket. Windows 2000 also supported IA-64, Alpha, MIPS and PowerPC processors. The Datacenter edition was likely used for very high end non-standard servers like the Unisys ES7000.

Comment: I don’t know about Windows itself, but SQL Server has a technique called slipstreaming, where you add service packs to an ISO.  It’s home rolled.

Comment: @zomega here’s [just one example of an eight-socket system](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/mp/6u/sys-681e-tr), and such machines aren’t new, even in the x86 world — I saw a four-socket 486-based system back in 1996. Eight-socket systems use more than one board, but there are [four-socket motherboards](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/x10qbi).

Comment: Another thing you need to be wary of. Even if you purchase the physical CDs, that's not necessarily enough to make it legal. The software itself (as opposed to the CD) is *licensed,* not sold. So, without a proper licence, use of the software will be a copyright violation.

Comment: @paxdiablo In the EU we have a law that the software producer (Microsoft) cannot forbid you to sell the software license to another person. https://curia.europa.eu/juris/liste.jsf?nat=or&mat=or&pcs=Oor&jur=C%2CT%2CF&num=C-128%252F11&for=&jge=&dates=&language=en&pro=&cit=none%252CC%252CCJ%252CR%252C2008E%252C%252C%252C%252C%252C%252C%252C%252C%252C%252Ctrue%252Cfalse%252Cfalse&oqp=&td=%3BALL&avg=&lgrec=de&lg=&page=1&cid=2515528

Comment: @RonJohn: You can slipstream Windows installations, including Windows 2000 - I did it back at the time, and there are many guides for it online.

Comment: @zomega: that may well be the case, I don't know much about EU law but it sounds eminently sensible. However, sites like WinWorld don't appear to be selling licences, they're just allowing downloads of the disk images. And, even if you buy from a "reputable" place, you need to ensure you're buying a valid licence, not just the physical media.

Comment: @paxdiablo I will buy CD & key online. I am only using Winworldpc to lookup CD types.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 2000 images on WinWorldPC are of CDs officially released by Microsoft.

The CDs don’t indicate explicitly which service pack they ship (if any), but their part number varies, so you might be able to find a list of part numbers corresponding to SP4.

The “1-4 processor edition” mention is accurate, see [this example](https://archive.org/details/Windows2000ServerSP1). Different editions of Windows 2000 supported different numbers of processors in a system.